# Mean with CDF approach

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

Since $$E[X]=\int_{0}^{\infty}\Pr[X\geq t]\,dt;~X\geq 0$$
I tried following in similar way with random variable $x$ which follows exponential distribution $e^{-x}$ for $x\geq 0$, and $a\geq 0,d\geq 1$:
$$E\left[\ln[1+(x+a)^{-d}]\right]=\int\Pr[\ln[1+(x+a)^{-d}]\geq t]\,dt=\int e^{-\left((e^t-1)^{-\frac{1}{d}}-a\right)}\,dt$$
However, I am not sure about the integration limits. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: It is unclear what you are doing, since you have introduced this new logarithmic function with new variables $a$ and $d$.  In any case, once you take logs you no longer have a non-negative random variable, and so the expected value equation you specify is inapplicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$E[Y]=\int_{0}^{\infty}\Pr[Y\geq t]\,dt;~Y\geq 0$$

Let $Y = \ln [1+(X+a)^{-d}]$

Assuming $a$, $d$ positive.

\begin{align}E[Y]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\Pr[Y\geq t]\,dt\\
&= \int_0^\infty \Pr[ [(X+a)^{-d}]\geq \exp(t)-1]\, dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty \Pr[ [(X+a)^d]\leq \frac1{\exp(t)-1}]\, dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty \Pr\left[ X\leq \left(\frac1{\exp(t)-1}\right)^\frac{1}{d}-a\right]\, dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty \Pr\left[ X\leq \max\left(\left(\frac1{\exp(t)-1}\right)^\frac{1}{d}-a,0\right)\right]\, dt \\\end{align}

Comment: Since the CDF $F_X(x)=1-e^{-x}$, can you please write the next step(s) with no $\max$?

Comment: $F_X(x)$ is only equal to that expression when $x$ is nonnegative. Otherwise, it is equal to $0$. It is good to find out when is the term positive as it simplify things.

Comment: Thanks @Siong, I got it.